# Java regular expression - word started with upper-case character - not only latin

Tags: java, regex

I try to find words in text, which started with upper-case letter. But I need to parse not only latin letters.
 Part of code:

```
String pattern = "[^[\\p{Upper}\\p{Lu}]\\w]";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
    word.set(itr.nextToken());
    Boolean m = word.toString().matches(pattern);

    if(m)
    {
        uid.set(word);
        context.write(uid, one);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Words that start with capital letters in Java can be found with

```
String pattern ="\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\b";
```

- `\b` - Word boundary
- `\p{Lu}` - Uppercase Unicode letter
- `\p{L}*` - Any Unicode letter, 0 or more repetitions
- `\b` - Word boundary

Sample code:

```
String str = "\u042F \u0425\u043E\u0436\u0443 \u043F\u043E \u0432\u043E\u0434\u0435.";
String rx = "\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*\\b";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```